# Set version in package.json to reference a version file

Tags: angular, git, npm, npm-version

Is there a way to use npm-version and not commit, to only change the version but leave it uncommitted?

I know that I can use `npm version {my-version}`, but is there an argument flag I can add so that the change isn't committed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can be disabled this on the command line by running `npm --no-git-tag-version {my-version}`. Then it will not create a *version commit* and *version tag*.

This will fail, if the working directory is **not** clean, unless the `-f` or `--force` flag is set.

see also [npm-version documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/version)